# .csproj files not getting checked in to TFS

Tags: tfs, windows-runtime, projects, checkin

My problem is that in my scenario, I have a project with two parallel project files for different build targets. I have a *ProjectName.WP8.csproj* and *ProjectName.WinRT.csproj*, which essentially include the same files.

I am trying to check-in this solution (*SolutionName.WinRT.sln*) to TFS and I get no errors. All the code changes to the code in the project goes through, but when I check the actual state of TFS, the (newer) *PorjectName.WinRT.csproj* files are not checked in.

This is quite peculiar since it worked perfectly for the WP8 version. How can I support this kind of scenario?

(If it's not possible, how do I easily migrate my parallel project to another TFS project?)

Comment: On the surface of it, there shouldn't be any issues with one TFS project housing a solution which consists of several projects of any type (WP, WinRT, Anything else). Can you elaborate on 'not checked in'  a bit. Does the project show as added to source control but not check in? does it appear checked in but when getting the latest, the latest files doesn't come back out?

Comment: I guess this might just be another case of "do it yourself, silly". I added a few existing projects to my solution (the solution is in TFS). What happens now is that the files in those projects get added to version control, but the .csproj files and Properties directories are not added. I just find this whole ordeal a bit confusin. My question was poorly phrased as the problem was really not the projects getting checked in but not even getting added to version control.

Comment: Had the same issue in VS2015 with a set of projects that were kind-of a copies of another projects (only a slight name change) and added to another solution. Wild guess: maybe a copy-paste issue because of a non-unique project GUIDs in the project files?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Just had this come up myself.  I had been working on a project for a few days before checking the solution in.  During the initial check in for the project, only the most recent file edits were seen by source control.  I was able to highlight all the files in the Solution Explorer and select Add to Source Control from the right click menu, but the csproj files themselves did not check in.  To do this, I had to go into the Source Control Explorer and open the project directory.  From within the directory, right click and select Add Items to Folder.  Then you can select the csproj files and you're good to go.

Comment: This didn't work for me because those files are not displayed in source control explorer on the local pane, yet they are in the physical working folder.  Instead, right-click in the local pane, choose Add Items to Folder, and select your .csproj/.vbproj file.  That will finally get it added to source control.  What a pain this issue has been!